# asyncio.gather vs list comprehension

Tags: python

In the following code, are `get_all_details_1` and `get_all_details_2` behave the same?

```
async def get_details(category, limit):
    async with limit:
        # ... 

limit = asyncio.Semaphore(4)
a_list = .... # a big list

async def get_all_details_1():
    b_list = await asyncio.gather(*[get_details(x, limit) for x in a_list])
    # ....


async def get_all_details_2():
    b_list = [await get_details(x, limit) for x in a_list]
    # ....
```

Comment: not exactly but the output is the same ... the gather is probably quite a bit faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not! Example:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def slowtask():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def gather():
    await asyncio.gather(*[slowtask() for _ in range(10)])

async def listcomp():
    [await slowtask() for _ in range(10)]

start = time.time()
asyncio.run(gather())
print("gather", time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
asyncio.run(listcomp())
print("listcomp", time.time() - start)
```

gives us:

```
gather 1.0030405521392822
listcomp 10.015443325042725
```

`asyncio.gather` properly allows multiple async tasks to run asynchronously while the list comprehension `await`s one after the other, leading to effectively serial code.

Comment: Will it be a problem for `asyncio.gather(.....)` accept a very long list of arguments?

Comment: @ca9163d9 I don't see why it would.

Comment: Only up to where performance begins to degrade or plateau when adding more coroutines to your gather.  Aiohttp only runs 100 connections at once so 10,000 GET requests might be better spread across many async threads or processes.

Comment: what if you did something like  asyncio.run([slowtask() for _ in range(10)])